# How to send Ctrl+z with gprs module

Tags: gprs, at-command

i want to send a picture with GPRS module and through a TCP connection to a server.
but my picture contains some "1a" (CTRL+Z) value in some bytes. As we know this is the terminator character for sending sms or data with AT commands. how can I send ctrl+z as a byte of data ?

Also when sending process reaches to character \0, it stops and returns an error. I mean GPRS module sends ERROR to serial port.
Example:

FF D8 FF E0 00 10

FF and D8 and FF and E0 will send successfully but error occurred at 00.
what is the problem?
thanks.

Comment: What TCP stack are you using?  On what platform?  How, specifically, are you trying to send the data?

Comment: on Windows i use these AT commands AT+CSTT="MYAPN";AT+CIPSTART="TCP","MYIP","MYPORT";AT+CIPSEND . after that i write bytes of picture to the serial port like FF D8 E0 00 10 .... and at the end i write 1A.

Comment: I could send text successfully but i couldn't send raw data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working on a project to sen sms from pc using AT Commands. Here I was  using following command  for ctrl+z.

```
outputStream.write(26);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try sending `0x1A`, or `$1A` if that doesn't work type $1A.